# Display expected value of a key measure daily excluding Weekends & Public Holidays in Power BI

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

There are two main measures displayed on a Power BI Report. One is the Actual value (team hour stats) and the other one is the expected value. The data is 'T-1' where 'T' is today. The team works Sun-Thurs. The expected value is currently being displayed daily using the below measure:

> Expected Overall % = CALCULATE((DAY(TODAY())-1)/(VAR t = TODAY()
> RETURN
> COUNTROWS(
> CALENDAR(
> FORMAT(t,"YYYY-MM-01") ,
> EDATE(FORMAT(t,"YYYY-MM-01"),1)-1
> )
> ))*100)

However, I am encountering the following issues:

- It does not exclude weekends and public holidays. Since the team work only during the weekdays, how can the expected value pause during weekends and public holidays automatically?
- The Actual value has a date slicer which gives values based on months, weeks etc. How can we also relate expected value along with it? Is this possible?

Note - I was able to create a custom date column with weekdays/weekends and public holidays.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Calendar table, you can use the function WEEKDAY() to check what day it is. Default 1 = Sunday; There is no function for a public holidays, but if you have a column for this information, you can exclude it as well.

for example:

```
calculate(countrows( CALCULATETABLE('Calendar', not(WEEKDAY('Calendar'[Date]) in {1,7} ), 'Calendar'[PublicHoliday] = 0 )
```